# What is the jQuery equivalent of React to check whether particular the DOM parent?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am looking for the functionality which can check whether we clicked inside a particular parent div?

I have a solution in `jQuery` but looking to do the same in `React js`.

Code in jQuery:

```
    var target=$(event.target);

    if (target.parents('div#sidenav').length) {
        console.log("this is side bar");
    }
    else{
        console.log("this is not side bar");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a use of `ref` in react.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      alert("You clicked INSIDE the sidebar.");
    } else {
      alert("You clicked OUTSIDE the sidebar.");
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar" ref={node => (this.node = node)}>
        Inside our div 1<br />
        <span>
          Inside our div 2
          <br />
          <span>Inside our div 3</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Refer this: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-shadow-gn91q

Comment: Really promising

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure javascript :

```
var domElement = document.getElementById("myId");

domElement.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var parentNode = event.target.parentNode;
    if (parentNode.id === "myId"){
        console.log("ok");
    } else {
        console.log("ko");
    }
});
```